# R: A 3d looking single dimension barplot

Tags: python, r, plot, bar-chart

I tried with the package [epade](http://rgm3.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=epade/man/bar3d.ade.rd&d=R_CC) but I failed!

Example:
Each one of the `x` values defines the height of each bar (bars as many `x` values exist, with `x` height).

```
xa<-c(9.45,6.79,14.03,7.25,16.16,19.42,16.30,4.60,14.76,19.24,
  16.04,7.80,13.16,10.00,15.76,16.29,19.52,27.22,7.74,6.75)
barplot(xa)
```

So I would like exactly the same plot in 3d looking fashion! 
Is it possible?

**UPDATED** **SOLUTION**
This was done in Python, not in R :(

Here is the code:

```
# needed modules
import csv
import pandas as pandas
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.interpolate import spline
from textwrap import wrap
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d
import pylab
import os

# we define some names in order to change only one
# 3 columnes are imported each time
# by changing col_inc from 0 to something
# we can define which range of columns will be imported
col_num = np.arange(2, 1001)
col_num_tuple = tuple(col_num)
cnt = col_num_tuple
cnt

# last counter col_inc = 279
col_inc = 273
str = 0 + col_inc
fin = 3 + col_inc
cols = cnt[str:fin]
cols

# importing a simple datafile, csv type. Data are comma seperated
# importing only 1st, 2nd and 4th columns
# We can call these data now by giving a new name, 'io'.

io = pandas.read_csv(
    '/data.csv', sep=",", usecols=cols)

# Try to get the name of singer & the name of song
# in the first two rows
names = io[0:2]
nm = names
nm1 = np.array(nm[:], dtype='string')
nm_singer = nm1[0:1][0:2, 1][0]
nm_song = nm1[1:2][0:2, 1][0]
nm_singer
nm_song
nms = nm_singer + ' - ' + nm_song

# we drop nan values
io = io.dropna()

# we make this in order not change each time, the name of column
io_all = np.array(io[3:])
io_st = np.array(io_all[:, 0], dtype=float)
io_end = np.array(io_all[:, 1], dtype=float)
io_dur = np.array(io_all[:, 2], dtype=float)
io_all
io_st
io_end
io_dur

# We define a new name for the column that is named alice inside io dataset
result = io_dur
# we need to make these data 'array type'
result = np.array(result)

# we now define the dimensions of our figure/plot, as well its dpi
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8), dpi=150)

# This line defines our first plot
# Afterwards, the '112' will define our second plot.
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
# ax1 = Axes3D(fig)

# we define here labels
xlabels = io_end
xpos = np.arange(xlabels.shape[0])
ylabels = np.array([''])
ypos = np.arange(ylabels.shape[0])
xposM, yposM = np.meshgrid(xpos, ypos, copy=False)

zpos = result
zpos = zpos.ravel()

# this defines the dimensions of the actual boxes
# you can play with these values.
dx = 0.7
dy = 0.7
dz = zpos

# here, we define ticks, they are placed in the 'middle' of each bar
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticks(xpos + dx / 2.)
ax1.w_xaxis.set_ticklabels(xlabels, rotation='vertical')
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticks(ypos + dy / 2.)
ax1.w_yaxis.set_ticklabels(ylabels)

# here we define the colors of the bars, rainbow style
# you can play with these numbers
values = np.linspace(0.2, 1., xposM.ravel().shape[0])
colors = cm.rainbow(values)

# figure subtitle
# fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)

# here, we define in the x axis the size of its ticks, its numbers
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=0, labelsize=7)

# Here, we define the limits of y axis,
# NOTE that this defines WHERE bars will be placed
# IN relation to the rest figure,
#  their offset point
plt.ylim((-2, 5))

# this says if the grid will be printed
plt.grid(True)
# this defines the placement of the 3d plot in its placeholders,
# in the surrounding white space
# I was surprised! The below line is not needed at all!
# fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, right=0, bottom=0, top=0)

# this is the actual command to define the plot
# all 6 parameters that we previously defined, are placed here.
# colors is an extra parameter
ax1.bar3d(xposM.ravel(), yposM.ravel(), dz * 0, dx, dy, dz, color=colors)

# elevation and azimuth, basically, definition of the view angle
ax1.view_init(0, -95)

# here we define that we will place a second plot
# Neither this line is needed!
# ax1 = fig.add_subplot(112, projection='3d')

# To produce numbers from 0 according to how many data exist in 'result'
x = np.arange(0, len(result))

y = result
# I try to center the line in relation to the top of bars.
y += 5
# Produce more points in order to make the line to look nicer (300).
x_smooth = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 300)
y_smooth = spline(x, y, x_smooth)

# smooth line sometimes went below zero in some extreme cases.
# Therefore I added this if statement to find these cases
# and increase the height of the smooth line so much points
# as the points that went below 0
if min(y_smooth) <= 0:
    y -= (min(y_smooth))-1
    y_smooth = spline(x, y, x_smooth)

# a trick to center the line to bars
x_smooth += 0.4
# here,i try to produce a 'z' array of so many zeros as the length
# of 'x_smooth line'
z = np.linspace(0, 0, len(x_smooth))

# here, we define the parameters of the second plot.
# ax1' symbol is duplicated
# in order to plot the line in the same plot with the barplot.
ax1.plot(x_smooth, z, y_smooth)

# this try to align the y title
ax1.annotate(
    '\n'.join(wrap('Duration of each Rythm (in sec)', 20)),
    xy=(0.20, 0.80), xytext=(0, 0), fontsize=8, color='steelblue',
    style='italic',
    xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
    bbox=dict(facecolor='mistyrose', alpha=0.3),
    horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='down')

# this try to align the x title
ax1.annotate(
    '\n'.join(wrap('Where Rythm is broken (in sec)', 20)),
    xy=(0.27, 0.06), xytext=(0, 0), fontsize=9, color='steelblue',
    xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
    bbox=dict(facecolor='peachpuff', alpha=0.3),
    horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='down')

# this try to center the bottom title
ax1.annotate(
    '\n'.join(wrap(nms, 100)), xy=(0.5, 0.07),
    xytext=(0, 0), fontsize=11,
    xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
    bbox=dict(facecolor='mediumorchid', alpha=0.3),
    horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='down')

# Eedefine path and filename in order to save in custom made filename
pathnm = '/'
filenm = nms
nflnm = '%s_3D.png' % filenm
npath = os.path.join(pathnm, nflnm)

# saving our plot
#fig.savefig(npath, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0,figsize=(46,15),dpi=400)
plt.show(fig)
io[0:2]'code'
```

Comment: Maybe worth to check the `bar3d.ade` function in the `epade` package. The `barplot` function you used is just the generic barplot function. Having said that, most people would strongly advise against plotting barplot with 3D effects as it can make comparison between elements difficult.

Comment: @BlankUsername finally i did it in python!

Comment: Excellent. Maybe post your code and the result here for others?

Comment: @BlankUsername I added my code (please correct my spelling / gramar errors, if you like!)